# Using ScreenSaverEngine with -background flag, does not open it in background

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, screensaver

I have used [this guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-the-wallpaper-your-mac-truly-deserves-with-a-bit-of-coding-f3149bbeb51) on Medium to use the screensaver as wallpaper.

I just got a new iMac at work with macOS v10.13.6. and was intending to do the same. But running the command in terminal with -background doesn't open the screensaver in the background anymore. Instead it's opening it in the front. I can still click stuff on the screen, but I can only see the screensaver.

/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background

Does anybody knows if the -background flag has changed?

Comment: Make sure you have a trailing `&`. The full command should be `/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &`

Comment: no the trailing & caused the terminal also to move the process to its background. In my case, I would have to restart the mac since I can't see anything but the screensaver... Without the & I can at least still cancel the app from the terminal with ctrl+c

Comment: this seems to still be an issue as of Monterey 12.0.1 :(